# Identify Hidden Characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, hidden-characters

In my SQL tables I have text which has hidden characters which is only visible when I copy and paste it in notepad++.

How to find those rows which has hidden characters using SQL Server queries?

I have tried comparing the lengths using `datalength` and `len`
it did not work.

```
DATALENGTH(name) AS BinaryLength != LEN(name)
```

I want the row which has hidden characters.

Comment: Is it a `varchar` or a `nvarchar` column? `DATALENGTH` returns byte count, so for `nvarchar` it returns double the length in characters. Is it always the same 'hidden character'?

Comment: It may also be pertinent to know what the hidden characters are.  What does Notepad++ show them to be?

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that this is being caused by control characters. Some of which are invisible. But also include tabs, newlines and spaces. An example to illustrate and how to get them to appear.

```
--DROP TABLE #SillyTemp

DECLARE @InvisibleChar1 NCHAR(1) = NCHAR(28), @InvisibleChar2 NCHAR(1) = NCHAR(30), @NonControlChar NCHAR(1) = NCHAR(33);
DECLARE @InputString NVARCHAR(500) = N'Some |' + @InvisibleChar1 +'| random string |' + @InvisibleChar2 + '|' + '; Thank god Finally a normal character |' + @NonControlChar + '|'; 
SELECT @InputString AS OhNoInvisibleCharacters

DECLARE @ControlCharRange NVARCHAR(50) = N'%[' + NCHAR(1) + '-' + NCHAR(31) + ']%';

CREATE TABLE #SillyTemp
(
    input nvarchar(500)
)

INSERT INTO #SillyTemp(input)
VALUES (@InputString),(N'A normal string')

SELECT @ControlCharRange;
SELECT input FROM #SillyTemp AS #SI WHERE input LIKE @ControlCharRange;
```

This produces 3 results. A string with invisiblechars within them like such:

> Some || random string ||; Thank god Finally a normal character |!|

Note, the  are actually invisible inside SQL. But stackoverflow shows them as such. The output in SQL Server is simply.

> Some || random string ||; Thank god Finally a normal character |!|

But these characters still have a corresponding (N)CHAR(X) value. (N)CHAR(0) is a NULL character and is highly unlikely to be in a string, in my setup to detect them it also provides some problems in building a range. (N)CHAR(32) is the ' ' space character.

The way the [X-Y] string operator works is also based on the (N)CHAR numbers. Therefore we can make a range of [NCHAR(1)-NCHAR(31)]

The last select goes through the temporary table, one which has invisible characters. Since we're looking for any NCHARS between 1 and 31, only those with invisible characters (and often invalid characters or tabs/newlines) satisfy the where condition. Thus only they get returned. In this case only the 'faulty' string gets returned in my select statement.